# Renaming files with numbers to corresponding 1-n numbers in order

Tags: files, sed, awk, rename

So I have a bunch of files in a folder, where a leading number represent the order of the file, but they are not the usual 1-n, like this:

```
2-file.txt
4-file.txt
7-file.txt
12-file.txt
```

and I want to have them in a sequential order from 1 to "number of files", preserving the numeric order, so:

```
1-file.txt
2-file.txt
3-file.txt
4-file.txt
```

where 1-file.txt is the previous 2-file.txt, 2-file.txt is the previous 4-file.txt and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script should do the job for you. Be sure to switch it from DEBUG to LIVE :

```
#!/bin/sh

list=`ls *-file.txt | sort -n`

i=1
for f in $list
do
    #DEBUG MODE
    echo "mv $f $i-file.txt"
    #LIVE MODE
    #mv $f $i-file.txt
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

And here is a version without the hardcoded extension:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z $1 ]
then
    echo "
You need to pass a prefix. For example:
 ${0##*/} -file.txt
"
    exit 1
fi

list=`ls *${1} | sort -n`

i=1
for f in $list
do
    #DEBUG MODE
    echo "mv $f ${i}${1}"
    #LIVE MODE
    #mv $f ${i}${1}
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

Comment: I think the answer would be more useful if it didn't hard code the `-file.txt` part of the names.

Comment: @icarus Updated the script. Personally, no need to over complicated the script as OP did not request anything special. The script would not work with spaces in file names too - but that was also not a request. I like the "keep it simple" design principle.